# How to convert multiple rows (in excel) in single sheet into multiple CSV file

Tags: sql, vba, excel, csv

I want to convert multiple rows(according to group) into multiple csv.
my single sheet in excel contain almost 3000 rows and 5 columns. now i want that each group from my excel sheet converts to csv file.

for example

1  `ali        Khan   ali.khan@hotmail.com        a1`

2  `juliet     ibm    juliet.ibm@hotmail.com      a1`

3  `laura      ann    lura.ann@hotmail.com        b1`

4  `abcd       ewqa   abcd.ewqa@hotmail.com       b1`

5  `annia     franics annia.franics@hotmail.com   c1`

now i want to extract these rows into separate CSV based on group (a1,b1,c1...).
Each group creates new csv.

Just need solution for this. Doesn't matter if you suggest any free tool or any code.

Comment: If you need one step solution I belive, you will have to write some VBA code, but I would just order it by group name, then saved it as single CSV file and finally manualy created (copy/paste) other csvs. I know it is not an elegant IT solution but it gets the job done!

Comment: Do you need an ongoing solution or just a one time solution.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I think @elrado is off to a good start, but rather than sorting/copying/pasting I would advise you (1) add a header row with `FirstName LastName Email Group` to row 1 then (2) use Excel's built in `Autofilter` features to hide all non-members of a group and finally (3) save each filtered group as a CSV

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you copy and paste in another sheet and create the CSV files.

```
Dim RowSt As Integer
Dim RowLs As Integer
Dim StriI As String
Dim StriL As String

RowSt = 4
RowLs = 4
StriI = Range("F" & RowLs).Value
StriL = Range("F" & RowLs).Value
While Range("F" & RowLs).Value <> ""
    StriL = Range("F" & RowLs).Value
    If StriL <> StriI Then
        Range("B" & RowSt & ":F" & RowLs - 1).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Selection.Clear
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="E:\0\A\" & StriI & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
        StriI = StriL
        RowSt = RowLs
    End If
    RowLs = RowLs + 1
Wend
Range("B" & RowSt & ":F" & RowLs - 1).Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.Clear
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="E:\0\A\" & StriI & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Till now I did it manually but Problem is, with time data is increasing and this is not ideal solution. So I have to figure out the way to deal with it. I will try with the code you guys send.